# Perform a single task on (220 choose 5) combination in a data frame

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have data with 220 rows. Initially choose 5 rows randomly and apply an operation to them. Now I have to perform a similar task on (220 choose 5) combination(That means 4102565544 data frames with 5 rows).Python is hitting memory issues when I use `list(itertools.combinations(list(range(0,222)),5))` and applying loop on each data frame with 5 rows is too much time-consuming. Below I have attached my data as a dictionary and I have replicated my problem set.

Data

```
df={'Name': {0: '004737367A89', 1: '006D631822DA', 2: '007FEEEF095D', 3: '015EA8035B5D', 4: '0168C7824FB3', 5: '02236A01C769', 6: '026A35601C28', 7: '03939D273F7D', 8: '05BE3A6A6344', 9: '0735B7F399C8', 10: '075F90DEDAAC', 11: '079D00DB87B6', 12: '08321FDDA475', 13: '084147D3DE00', 14: '08693ADAF466', 15: '08EE69FF7C9B', 16: '0996F835D14B', 17: '0A061E004649', 18: '0BDADD43DF2D', 19: '0D580A803B2C', 20: '11DCF10E0F76', 21: '1241EC5AC73C', 22: '150595F71A7A', 23: '160D7B436114', 24: '1805135DA1B7', 25: '18D26316EA11', 26: '1B744908A7E9', 27: '1CB417508187', 28: '1EA75E92E370', 29: '1F1B4DA40CE4', 30: '209D86760A9C', 31: '228BC53DB280', 32: '235D0F9A5E0E', 33: '2452814BCC90', 34: '2923CA6C88B1', 35: '2CB60EF30BAA', 36: '2CD7BD1FC443', 37: '2D03FAC79D60', 38: '2F34FFA27A7C', 39: '2F8F282FDCEE', 40: '3.03891E+11', 41: '31B4A8BDBA5F', 42: '34EC4E7D8E15', 43: '3695444ADBFF', 44: '370F1D138305', 45: '3826943C86AF', 46: '39F11738A59D', 47: '39F2FF0A2E05', 48: '3A8B6F61E548', 49: '3B256CE48F60', 50: '3C09C2C73655', 51: '3D6858B43366', 52: '3D94154B544C', 53: '3DDD62DDF6C4', 54: '3EBDAFB8E7EE', 55: '408B3D0EAF85', 56: '40ED913F4BB6', 57: '43380E855E4E', 58: '44C8332521DE', 59: '4817047FFAC1', 60: '481896BC4240', 61: '49263E82B2B8', 62: '4AF76F8D6BBB', 63: '4BC2016E5222', 64: '4CCF2D4FF5EC', 65: '4E9750936994', 66: '4F61F6A5588D', 67: '505F16F25595', 68: '50756E6D3B32', 69: '50E1E1F5F31D', 70: '516B4C9C3F45', 71: '52608C24A09E', 72: '52B2EBC622A6', 73: '539B8164BD32', 74: '5462E581A288', 75: '55149C502434', 76: '55D8B9306A65', 77: '5808368AFA0A', 78: '58F6BA305E2A', 79: '58FE73C690DA', 80: '596857EDC73F', 81: '599DF7F0CB41', 82: '59F1F27E85F4', 83: '5AE11428142F', 84: '5B27B574EA5B', 85: '5D3FA98DDD61', 86: '5DE6CFC7E471', 87: '5DF85F5EA21C', 88: '5EA87B759595', 89: '5EAA2E0BEAA2', 90: '5EAFEBA99A30', 91: '5EFC03FC84DF', 92: '5F6A8D18E234', 93: '6008B6021BAA', 94: '63765F49AC32', 95: '64099F419232', 96: '652349DF5059', 97: '6551FB43EE37', 98: '6613C12B0634', 99: '66C312BFDFD6', 100: '66D964D2E1D0', 101: '6790A35547E2', 102: '67A2603888E5', 103: '6991A9411704', 104: '6CFC28C22836', 105: '6D5DAED137C9', 106: '6EBB87FAD022', 107: '6EF1206450AF', 108: '70C74C90C3E2', 109: '71168B36CCFD', 110: '7177392ADD8B', 111: '74AF6AA78FB9', 112: '759CFBB05E2F', 113: '771E8EA5A4C7', 114: '7740740D57BE', 115: '7926DFB85C8B', 116: '7A6091203844', 117: '7C23D53CE5DD', 118: '7C4ED1AA239F', 119: '7E0C21E0010F', 120: '80E9914A0BF8', 121: '82867FEAF519', 122: '82C735B34C85', 123: '85EF1FFBAC47', 124: '872F22A4D018', 125: '87C72000AAB2', 126: '8978B70E88C3', 127: '8ADEF3F17E42', 128: '8B5F4EE22DF5', 129: '8B757ED14D67', 130: '8E0C10341AA8', 131: '90289E4E68F6', 132: '9259DEED6524', 133: '92754763710B', 134: '92B164934E01', 135: '96DBA1873BFF', 136: '97E7144ECEF9', 137: '9AE4EB9DF4F0', 138: '9CAC53908EE1', 139: '9F31161E7BDF', 140: 'A090B8A939CB', 141: 'A12E89E87CB5', 142: 'A31CA572620F', 143: 'A4263AA51F9A', 144: 'A540D6615FA0', 145: 'A56804CE6BAF', 146: 'A60313C4FC06', 147: 'A612803F81BA', 148: 'A77E12FFA171', 149: 'A87B6602E946', 150: 'AADE28D99973', 151: 'AEB37BE9DBFF', 152: 'B04ACAB6A193', 153: 'B41004303288', 154: 'B454AAFDA2AF', 155: 'B701B4E2F2BF', 156: 'B7EF621EC0AE', 157: 'B9084B8E2378', 158: 'BA8C4B0E8378', 159: 'BBD01B2776A8', 160: 'BE5377A632DF', 161: 'BE8D95B26DEE', 162: 'BEEB25AC3BB3', 163: 'BF585F42B5F6', 164: 'BF889C615B6A', 165: 'C1934D47BC69', 166: 'C31934680839', 167: 'C43F40D3D865', 168: 'C4955BCC1F0C', 169: 'C4F03F22DE3E', 170: 'C5BC9B26046C', 171: 'C5D2BE738C56', 172: 'C762399CAF83', 173: 'C7B9B444D117', 174: 'C943B9F6FDDF', 175: 'C9C7138CAF65', 176: 'CB66BE597E30', 177: 'CC7DA44E344E', 178: 'CE81A7E65B6B', 179: 'CE971F87D0B5', 180: 'CECC8C16ECAB', 181: 'D111860A3AC1', 182: 'D159C02757AE', 183: 'D33BB70DCA77', 184: 'D386F0671D80', 185: 'D43B801CCCA9', 186: 'D465BE3D4A94', 187: 'D49E08EEC650', 188: 'D4BD5D5DD7E4', 189: 'D64F455CB56A', 190: 'D6D99F00B58B', 191: 'D7774555E609', 192: 'D7CDFD417C01', 193: 'DBF16B9938A4', 194: 'DCC2FA798C09', 195: 'DE6E090827B8', 196: 'E25F5A55A4D8', 197: 'E5A82C4E86C7', 198: 'E5AC30A8337B', 199: 'E6EBC0EFBF18', 200: 'EB9BBBA2FEB9', 201: 'EC8A20CAC153', 202: 'EC8EA44FDACD', 203: 'ECB284CBDDA7', 204: 'EED0F8B3B968', 205: 'EF4B578B0902', 206: 'F13986786A7A', 207: 'F17F0E81FC73', 208: 'F34CFBCB7A28', 209: 'F396C1E8BF59', 210: 'F40ED923507F', 211: 'F87A72CF9671', 212: 'F8CDE15A2FCB', 213: 'F9032EE897A9', 214: 'FAC08B5AA521', 215: 'FB3071FBA3BC', 216: 'FC6435726337', 217: 'FD5F2F4D32D7', 218: 'FD6E925243AA', 219: 'FDA85734568D', 220: 'FF18E7D41654', 221: 'FFEC03758A05'}, 'Code': {0: 375000, 1: 275000, 2: 225000, 3: 275000, 4: 175000, 5: 275000, 6: 295000, 7: 525000, 8: 175000, 9: 135000, 10: 275000, 11: 250000, 12: 275000, 13: 350000, 14: 225000, 15: 175000, 16: 395000, 17: 275000, 18: 225000, 19: 195000, 20: 225000, 21: 175000, 22: 135000, 23: 225000, 24: 250000, 25: 225000, 26: 250000, 27: 295000, 28: 275000, 29: 250000, 30: 275000, 31: 250000, 32: 295000, 33: 195000, 34: 275000, 35: 195000, 36: 275000, 37: 175000, 38: 525000, 39: 225000, 40: 350000, 41: 135000, 42: 295000, 43: 195000, 44: 495000, 45: 495000, 46: 275000, 47: 375000, 48: 295000, 49: 250000, 50: 250000, 51: 225000, 52: 175000, 53: 250000, 54: 475000, 55: 135000, 56: 350000, 57: 225000, 58: 250000, 59: 275000, 60: 225000, 61: 295000, 62: 225000, 63: 250000, 64: 225000, 65: 250000, 66: 135000, 67: 175000, 68: 295000, 69: 175000, 70: 295000, 71: 295000, 72: 225000, 73: 225000, 74: 365000, 75: 295000, 76: 225000, 77: 195000, 78: 225000, 79: 225000, 80: 225000, 81: 295000, 82: 135000, 83: 195000, 84: 295000, 85: 550000, 86: 250000, 87: 225000, 88: 275000, 89: 225000, 90: 295000, 91: 250000, 92: 250000, 93: 225000, 94: 175000, 95: 250000, 96: 175000, 97: 350000, 98: 175000, 99: 275000, 100: 295000, 101: 225000, 102: 225000, 103: 195000, 104: 175000, 105: 350000, 106: 175000, 107: 275000, 108: 275000, 109: 175000, 110: 195000, 111: 225000, 112: 275000, 113: 375000, 114: 135000, 115: 135000, 116: 395000, 117: 295000, 118: 195000, 119: 275000, 120: 195000, 121: 375000, 122: 195000, 123: 275000, 124: 275000, 125: 175000, 126: 325000, 127: 275000, 128: 250000, 129: 135000, 130: 175000, 131: 195000, 132: 550000, 133: 225000, 134: 250000, 135: 350000, 136: 495000, 137: 275000, 138: 135000, 139: 175000, 140: 175000, 141: 225000, 142: 175000, 143: 275000, 144: 325000, 145: 295000, 146: 275000, 147: 275000, 148: 175000, 149: 350000, 150: 550000, 151: 250000, 152: 350000, 153: 325000, 154: 175000, 155: 250000, 156: 175000, 157: 250000, 158: 275000, 159: 225000, 160: 195000, 161: 175000, 162: 225000, 163: 275000, 164: 225000, 165: 135000, 166: 250000, 167: 225000, 168: 175000, 169: 275000, 170: 175000, 171: 275000, 172: 175000, 173: 195000, 174: 325000, 175: 275000, 176: 295000, 177: 350000, 178: 350000, 179: 425000, 180: 225000, 181: 135000, 182: 150000, 183: 135000, 184: 350000, 185: 225000, 186: 375000, 187: 175000, 188: 295000, 189: 195000, 190: 350000, 191: 175000, 192: 225000, 193: 195000, 194: 195000, 195: 350000, 196: 250000, 197: 175000, 198: 175000, 199: 395000, 200: 175000, 201: 225000, 202: 175000, 203: 350000, 204: 175000, 205: 250000, 206: 375000, 207: 275000, 208: 525000, 209: 175000, 210: 375000, 211: 295000, 212: 275000, 213: 175000, 214: 325000, 215: 250000, 216: 195000, 217: 275000, 218: 250000, 219: 135000, 220: 195000, 221: 135000}}
```

What I want is to select random 5 rows first

```
import random
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
inputt=pd.DataFrame({"NameID":data1.Name[random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)]})
for i in range(len(inputt.index)):
      D1 = data[data["Name"] == inputt["NameID"].iloc[i]]
      D2 =  D2.append(D1)

values=D2.Code       
real_sum=values.sum()
```

and then I want to perform the same operation on the rest of the rows in the data frame and figure which data frame with such rows has sum less than the real_sum.Is there any simulation technique I can apply here  or anything else ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use the whole data set? In this kind of performance problem, it is always better to start with a small sample to apply different operations or functions and improve them progressively.

Comment: @NicolasM I have to tell users instantly that if you use these combinations your sum will be better thats why I need whole dataframe. Firstly person will randomly select say 5 rows(IDs), a sum will be generated from selected 5 IDs. My portal must tell person that now if you select these 5 your sum will improve I cannot skip any row can I?

Comment: Do you need to have an absolute optimum? I've been already in front of this kind of issue, and even if you take a random sample of 10% and you get the best result among them, the result is good enough for most users. Otherwise, you should focus on performance optimisation, using all your processors, maybe cloud computation (expensive), and performance code (use of dictionnary instead of pandas dataframe, etc.).

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean by absolute optimum?

Comment: It means that you need to take the whole data set to get the best values from them, which requires full calculation.

Comment: @NicolasM Yes you are right I need that. Maximum sum out of all combinations.

Comment: In that case, you need calculation power, either by optimizing functions (use of dict) or multi threading or cloud computing.

Comment: @NicolasM Thanks for you input.

Comment: Hi @Daman, can you explain your use case? As far as I understand it, you want user to randomly select 5 rows from a single dataframe and then you want to tell them whether they have the highest sum possible from that dataframe? Your first dataframe df1 has shape (220,1)? I don't then understand the role of the other dataframes?

Comment: yes you are right I have one data frame. User select 5 rows and see the sum of those 5 rows. What I want is to give all the possible data frames with 5 rows other than what user has selected from 220 rows. The other data frames are the combinations of 5 different rows from 220 rows and their sum is more than what user's selected rows sum. Was I able to clear your doubt?